# fstab wont mount share, cant see what im doing wrong?

Tags: samba, fstab, cifs

I had this working until a reinstall today. My home folder was on another disk so my `~/.smbcredentials` file is fine. So it must be my `fstab` or application not installed. I have `cif-utils` installed and I've checked my search history for the guide i used but i can't seem to get it to work.

```
//kaboom.local/media    /home/noki/KaboomMedia  cifs    credentials=/home/noki/.smbcredentials,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8,noperm   0   0
```

On `sudo mount -a` I get:

```
mount error(95): Operation not supported
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

Through Unity, I get it to mount through the `cifs` option and I can `ping kaboom.local` and get a response. Stupidly didn't backup my `fstab`, will this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FIXED: I was missing a portion of the line in fstab, it seems I was incorrectly providing information about my user. Simply use 'id' to get this information on your system to apply to you're own fstab entry:

```
//kaboom.local/media    /home/noki/KaboomMedia  cifs    credentials=/home/noki/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,dir_mode=0777,gid=1000,uid=1000,sec=ntlm  0   0
```

Not sure if all of those options are required but it is now working for me.